# Phonegap 3.7 / jQuery Mobile iOS 7 Clicking submit button when keyboard open creates smaller screen and doesn't submit form

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

- Problem only happens when clicking on the forms submit button.
- Closing the keyboard with the done button allows submit button to submit.
- Clicking the GO button on the keyboard also submits the form.
- Also the forgot password link I have which is a generic a href also has the same problem under the same conditions.
- In iOS 9 the problem doesn't exist
- On android the problem doesn't exist

My assumption is it's not related to the specific code because even the href is having the same effect. I've tried countless changes to the code to get this to work but nothing seems to resolve it.

Here's the code:

```
            <form id="login-form" class="custom-form" method="POST">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="required email" type="email" name="email" id="email">

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input minlength="6" class="required" type="password" id="password" name="password">

            </div>
            <div class="form-action-bar">
                <div style="text-align:left;" onclick="window.location = 'recoverPassword.html';">
                    <a id="recoverPassword">
                        <span id='lblChangePassword'>Forgot Password?</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-role="button" value="Login">
             </div>
        </form>

            $(document).on("pagecreate", '#login-page', function(event) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $("#login-form").validate({
                onfocusout: false,
                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    element.parent().after(error);
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: "This field is required.",
                        email: "This email address is not valid."
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function() {
                    server.login($('#email').val(), $('#password').val(), function(response) {
                        if (response.invalid == 1) {
                            $("#errormsg").html(translate(language, 'Invalid User Login'));
                            $("#errormsg").show();
                            localStorage.removeItem('userinfo');
                            localStorage.removeItem('uniqueID');                                
                        } else {
                            localStorage.setItem("uniqueID", response.data.useruniqueID);
                            localStorage.setItem('userinfo', JSON.stringify(response.data));

                            if (response.data.officeid) {
                                localStorage.setItem("agencyid", response.data.officeid);
                                server.getAgency(response.data.officeid, localStorage.getItem("uniqueID"), function(data) {
                                    if (data.invalid == 1) {
                                        $("#errormsg").html(translate(language, 'Invalid Agency Id'));
                                        $("#errormsg").show();
                                        localStorage.removeItem('officeinfo');
                                        localStorage.removeItem('staffinfo');
                                        localStorage.removeItem('agencyid');
                                        window.location = 'selectagency.html';
                                    } else {
                                        var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(data);
                                        localStorage.setItem('officeinfo', dataToStore);
                                        console.log('office info: ' + dataToStore);
                                        window.location = 'index.html';
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                window.location = 'selectagency.html';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it wasn't specific to Phonegap but a problem with jQuery Mobile, iOS browsers (Safari and Chrome), and particular css styles.

The issue was that there was a position: fixed; attribute on the html element and that was somehow conflicting with jQuery Mobile causing specifically input type="submit" or input type="button" to become unresponsive when the iOS keyboard was on screen.